# Create 'Link' in an AlertView Action

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

Ok, not sure if this is possible, but basically I have a long press gesture recognizer which opens up an alert. What I want is when the alert appears, the user will click the button, and it will open a link in safari. Code:

```
        if sender.state == .began
        {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message:
                "Open Product in Safari", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Safari", style: .default,handler: nil))

            present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the button will say "Go to Safari", and I want that button to take them to the link. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `handler` closure to take an action when the button is tapped. 
Following is an example:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message:
            "Open Product in Safari", preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Safari",
                                                style: .default,
                                                handler: { action in
                                                    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "www.mylinktobeopenedinsafari.com")!, options: [:]) { _ in
                                                        print("Link opened")
                                                    }
        }))

present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: @cgreene accept the answer if it's worked. It will help to other users.